# Как можно сделать красивее код php?

Tags: php, ооп

Когда имеется множество вложенных **if - else** в ООП?

Задал переменную флаг:

```
private $error = array('status' => true);
```

И можно поступить так:

```
if (empty($this->dataPost)) $this->error['status'] = false;
```

и дальше вызвать метод **CheckError()**, который проверит, значение

```
$this->error['status']
```

на **true**, и в случае успеха вызовет конечную функцию, которая добавит данные в БД.

Но решение не красивое, потому что после каждого **(!if)**, нужно устанавливать этот флаг ошибки и вызывать **CheckError()**

Comment: Покопаем, возможно это решит проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А пробовали использовать [исключения](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php)?